# Testing Exceptions in Nunit 3.0 and above

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit

I am trying to test an exception, NUnit 3.11 is giving me the error, and the unit test is failing. I want Nunit to green pass if it receives this exception, not error out. How would I resolve this?

Feel free to improve code if you want, just started learning programming few months ago.

When running it gives the exception itself, does not pass.

Test errors out- Message: System.ArgumentException : Too much data

```
public class ParseVendorSupply
{
    public VendorSupply FromCsv(string csvLine)
    {
        string[] values = csvLine.Split(',');
        if (values.Length > 3)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Too much data");
        }
        VendorSupply vendorsupply = new VendorSupply();
        vendorsupply.VendorId = Convert.ToInt16(values[0]);
        vendorsupply.ProductId = Convert.ToInt16(values[1]);
        vendorsupply.Quantity = Convert.ToInt16(values[2]);
        return vendorsupply;
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
public class ParseVendorSupplyNunit
{

    ParseVendorSupply parseVendorSupplytest = new ParseVendorSupply();

    [Test]
    public void FromCsv_ParseCorrectly_Extradata()
    {
        string csvLineTest = "5,8,3,9,5";
        //VendorSupply vendorsupply = parseVendorSupplytest.FromCsv(csvLineTest);
        Assert.That(parseVendorSupplytest.FromCsv(csvLineTest), Throws.ArgumentException);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers that suggest using an `Action` work, but the `Action` is not necessary for NUnit. I'm creating this one because I think it's important that you understand **why** your existing code doesn't work.

Problem is that the first argument of your assert calls the method **before calling the assert**. Your `Assert.That` never gets called since the exception is thrown while evaluating the argument.

Defining an `Action` avoids this problem because it specifies a method call that won't be made immediately.

However, a more colloquial way to specify this in NUnit is by using a `lambda` directly...

```
Assert.That(() => parseVendorSupplytest.FromCsv(csvLineTest), Throws.ArgumentException);
```

Comment: Sure. I tend to forget this is a social media application. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the method you are testing as an `Action`. You can then use the `Assert.Throws<>` method:

```
Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => parseVendorSupplytest.FromCsv(csvLineTest));
```

There is also an `async` version if you are using `async/await`

```
Assert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentException>(async () => await parseVendorSupplytest.FromCsv(csvLineTest));
```

Comment: Which is better to use Assert.That or Assert.Throw<T> to check something like BusinessLayer Exceptions or DataLayer Exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

**Wrap method** you are testing into an `Action`

```
Action parseFromCsv = () => parseVendorSupplytest.FromCsv(csvLineTest);
Assert.That(parseFromCsv, Throws.ArgumentException)
```

And when testing for common exceptions, such as `ArgumentException`, always test for exception message as well.
Because common exception can occur in some other places and test will pass for a wrong reason.

I prefer to use FluentAssertions, which I found little bid more readable.

```
Action parseFromCsv = () => parseVendorSupplytest.FromCsv(csvLineTest);
parseFromCsv.Should().Throw<ArgumentException>().WithMessage("Too much data");
```